# PHP ZipArchive list only one level of files/folders

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have wp.zip and would like to list only one level of files/folders. My current code:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open('wp.zip'), \ZipArchive::RDONLY);

for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
 $stat = $zip->statIndex($i);
 echo $stat['name'] . ' ';
}
```

This code spits out entire list of files recursively.

I need only first level, like this:

```
wp-admin/ 
wp-content/ 
index.php 
config.php 
<...>
```

What's the best approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: There is no concept of level in zip, analyze the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can only parse the name and get the level of the file accordingly.

```
<?php

$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open('wp.zip');

function getEntryList($zip, $level = 1){
    $res = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; ++$i){
        $name = explode("/", trim($zip->statIndex($i)['name'],"/"));
        if(count($name) == $level + 1){
            $res[] = end($name);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

print_r(getEntryList($zip));
```

Comment: Ha, $level = 0 does what I need! Thank you.